# How to move files where the first line contains a string?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, redhat

I am currently using the following command:

```
grep -l -Z -E '.*?FindMyRegex' /home/user/folder/*.csv | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} /home/destination/folder
```

This works fine. The problem is it uses `grep` on the entire file.

I would like to use the `grep` command on the FIRST line of the file only.

I have tried to use `head -1 file |` at the beginning, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

A change I would add to your script is -

```
     for file in *.csv; do 
        head -1 "$file" | grep -l -Z -E '.*?FindMyRegex' | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} /home/destination/folder; 
     done
```

Comment: Using just `head -1 file | ...` instead of `echo $(head ...) | ...` is not only shorter and more efficient, but also safer. Right now you may mangle the first line due to missing quotes. Also I think `grep -l` won't work here as the input is coming from a pipe. You may want to use `grep -q ... && mv "$file" ...`.

Comment: Hi thanks, I am getting 2 errors:

1 for file names with space in them.

2 is for when the grep matches: mv: cannot stat '(standard input)'...

Answer (score 0):

you can maybe try `sed '1q' file.csv | grep ...` to search the regexp only in the first line.

Comment: mv: cannot stat 'standard input' no such file or directory
(I moved the file part from the grep to sed)

Comment: if you are still using `grep -l`, then the output will be `(standard input)`, which will not work with mv. The answer with awk given below is probably more adapted to your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk 'FNR==1{if($0~/PATTERN/)
    printf "mv %s %s\n",FILENAME, "/target";nextfile}' /path/*.csv
```

- First of all, in your regex: `.*?FindMyRegex` the `.*?` doesn't make any sense, they could be removed.
- The above awk (gawk) one-liner will build up `mv file target`  command lines for you. You can check them, if you are satisfied with them, pipe the output to `|sh` , the commands are gonna be executed.
- replace `PATTERN` by your regex pattern, and `/target` by the real target dir.
- The one-liner is assuming that the filenames don't contain special chars (space i.e.), if it is the case, add `"`s to the `mv` cmd.

Comment: @Socowi what I meant  `.*?Pattern`  doesn't make sense. no matter it is greedy or not.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you meant: `grep` looks for matches in the whole line, not only matches starting at the beginning of the line. Here we are not interested in the matching part, only in the yes/no answer, therefore `.*pattern` is the same as just `pattern`. And if the non-greedy regex `.*?pattern` was understood by `grep -E`, it would always match just `pattern` because there is nothing in front of `.*?`.

Comment: @Socowi yes, apart from if non-greedy is supported by `-E or -P`, the `.*?`  or  `.*` in his pattern doesn't make sense.

Comment: probably want to quote the filename in the printf statement output. quoting will get messy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `grep` or `find`, as long as your files don't have embedded newlines.
I don't know an easy way off the top of my head to get `sed` to delimit with nulls.

```
mv $( for f in  /home/user/folder/*.csv;
      do sed -ns '1 { /yourPattern/F; q; }' $f;
      done ) /home/destination/folder/
```

> EDIT

Rewrote with a loop. This will run a separate instance of `sed` to check each file, but at least it shouldn't read beyond the first line. It *will* fail syntactically if there are no hits.

You *might* need `-E` depending on your regex.

`-n` says don't print records from the files.
`-s` says treat each file as a distinct input - this is so the filenames aren't always the first one.

This *does* require GNU `sed` for the `F`.

Comment: the `sed` in your command will read all lines in each file. Even though it only does some logic on 1st line.

Comment: Yep. I had a `2q` but it was quitting the entire process on the first file. One would *wish* it had a simple optimizer that recognized there was only one line to read and no output to generate, but I wouldn't assume. This is a case where `awk` kinda shines. :)

Answer (score 0):

using GNU awk to find the filenames, pipe the filenames into xargs

```
gawk -v pattern="myRegex" '
    FNR == 1 {if ($0 ~ pattern) printf "%s\0", FILENAME; nextfile}
' *.csv | xargs -0 echo mv -t destination
```

If it looks OK, remove "echo"

Comment: Hi, I specified the path for the csv before the wildcard.
Got an error 
mv: missing file operand

Comment: Run just the gawk command without piping to xargs: are any filenames printed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob   # Globs that match nothing expand to nothing
shopt -s dotglob    # Globs match files whose names start with '.'

dest=/home/destination/folder

for file in *.csv ; do
    head -n 1 -- "$file" | grep -qE '.*?FindMyRegex' && mv -- "$file" "$dest"
done
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` prevents an error if there are no `.csv` files in the directory.
- `shopt -s dotglob` ensures that files whose name starts with '.' are handled.
- The `--` in the options for `head` and `mv` ensures that files whose names begin with `-` are handled correctly.
- The quotes in `"$file"` and `"$dest"` ensure that names that contain whitespace (actually `$IFS`) characters (including newlines) or glob metacharacters are handled correctly.

Note that the `.*?` in the reqular expression is probably redundant, and may not do what you think it does (`grep -E` doesn't do  non-greedy matching).